# How to match characters between two occurrences of the same but random string

Tags: regex, go

Base string looks like:

```
repeatedRandomStr ABCXYZ /an/arbitrary/@#-~/sequence/of_characters=I+WANT+TO+MATCH/repeatedRandomStr/the/rest/of/strings.etc
```

The things I know about this base string are:

- `ABCXYZ` is constant and always present.
- `repeatedRandomStr` is random, but its first occurrence is always at the beginning and before `ABCXYZ`

So far I looked at regex context matching, recursion and subroutines but couldn't come up with a solution myself.

My currently working solution is to first determine what `repeatedRandomStr` is with:

`^(.*)\sABCXYZ`

and then use:

`repeatedRandomStr\sABCXYZ\s(.*)\srepeatedRandomStr`

to match what I want in `$1`. But this requires two separate regex queries. I want to know if this can be done in a single execution.

Comment: Maybe you want to match one or more non-whitespace chars? `repeatedRandomStr\sABCXYZ\s+(\S+)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't know what `repeatedRandomStr` is at first. And no, that white space before the second occurrence of `repeatedRandomStr` can't be relied on. I'll edit my question.

Comment: If you cannot explain what "*My currently working solution is to first determine what repeatedRandomStr is*" we cannot help you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I meant that I use a simple regex query. I use `^(.*)\sABCXYZ`. and then I use the one mentioned in the question. The point is that __my currently working solution__ requires two separate regex query. I'm want to know if it can be done in one single query.

Comment: Try `^(.*?)\s+ABCXYZ\s(.*)\1` and get Group 2.

Comment: Can you ensure that `ABCXYZ` never occurs inside `repeatedRandomStr`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much. That works! I read on and on...
I thought that `backreference` is only possible inside a _replace_ query!

Comment: @cyberbrain In my case, yes. And Wiktor solution works for me. But still it will be interesting to know what would be the implications if that wasn't the case.

Comment: The implication would be that you get the wrong result in the second group, as it would at least contain the `ABCXYZ` string and maybe a part of the `repeatedRandomStr`.  So you should work with a minimum or exact length limitation for `repeatedRandomStr` if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Go, where RE2 library is used, there is no way other than yours: keep extracting the value before the `ABCXYZ` and then use the regex to match a string between two strings, as [RE2 does not and won't support backreferences.](https://github.com/google/re2/issues/101)

In case the regex flavor can be switched to PCRE or compatible, you can use

```
^(.*?)\s+ABCXYZ\s(.*)\1
^(.*?)\s+ABCXYZ\s(.*?)\1
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5mP0Ti/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `ABCXYZ` - some constant string
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(.*)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\1` -  the same value as in Group 1.

Comment: Thanks again. But to be fair this doesn't work in golang, where I intended to use it. Apparently no `backreference` of this kind is supported in golang. See this https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax.
But I leave your answer marked as it works anywhere else except golang.

Comment: @eternal That is of course not working in RE2, and will never work since they are not going to add backreference support. You will need to so that in two steps as before. You **should mention the regex usage environment when asking regex questions**. Regex is not invariant, it is always library-dependent.